# Elasticsearch spend 80% time in build_scorer

Tags: elasticsearch

We have upgraded our ES from ES-2.3 to ES-6.4. So we have done reindexing of all our indexes.

Now while running the query to new elasticsearch, we got performance with such queries :

```
 {
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "visitTime": {
                  "gte": "2018-07-18T18:30:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "source"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: As shown in image ES query taking around 70% of total time in **build_scorer**.]

So my question is why ES query taking much time in build_scorer ????
When running the same query in ES 2.3, take much less time.

Comment: You should simply replace `must` with `filter`

Comment: tried, no gain in performance.

when I am viewing elasticsearch log, found out this line 
"not opting out of the query cache; authorization is not allowed"
I done understand what this means ?